# java Redis client to connect to multiple aws read replica endpoints?

Tags: java, redis

I would like to use Jedis client to connect to my aws Redis read endpoints, could someone point me to how to do that? Some code example would be great.

If Jedis could not do that (it is not clear from the Jedis source code), any other Java Redis client can do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This answer has two parts of which the second is the magic part:

1. You connect to AWS ElastiCache in the same way like you would do it with a normal Redis server.
2. Behind the scenes, AWS uses some magic to failover nodes. This is not handled like with Redis Sentinel but an internal mechanism. Additionally, AWS ElastiCache can change the IP address behind a hostname which is an issue to most client libraries as they use Java domain name resolution that caches the DNS responses.

Your best bet for now would be using [Redisson](https://github.com/mrniko/redisson/). They also have an [example](https://github.com/mrniko/redisson/wiki/2.-configuration#25-elasticache-mode) how to set up their client to connect AWS ElastiCache.

Comment: Update: Lettuce supports now [Master/Slave](https://github.com/mp911de/lettuce/wiki/Master-Slave) connections utilizing either the master only or using the whole ElastiCache cluster together with its slaves.